# Hockey-SDK In-App Update feature?

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I'm using `Hockey-SDK` in my app and a few of my testers have requested that I implement their In-App Update feature so they can be notified I guess when there is a new build available. I've never used this feature before, never used `Hockey-SDK` before, so I was wondering if anyone could point me to how to implement this.

I obviously did check their docs first, and found a section for this, although I found it almost too simple to understand correctly. To enable this feature when distributing via Ad-Hoc, but NOT enable it when it is uploaded to the App Store (how do they make that check by the way?), do I do this in my `AppDelegate.m`?

```
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:@"1ef7a1d2b1d0fd2b0a1f06d7355f6005"];
// Do some additional configuration if needed here
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] setDisableUpdateManager: NO];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator
 authenticateInstallation];
```

I guess I found it a bit confusing they'd use the wording `setDisableUpdateManager:`. Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The In-App-Update feature is enabled by default and automatically disabled when distributed via the AppStore (not in Testflight!).

So you don't need to add this line. See the documentation here: http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.7.1/Classes/BITHockeyManager.html#//api/name/disableUpdateManager

To get it work, make sure to upload new versions to HockeyApp with increasing values for `CFBundleVersion` (Build number). If you have any issues with the feature, please contact us at http://support.hockeyapp.net

Comment: from 3.8.3 it will not prompt in TestFlight as well: https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/73667-will-store-type-release-prompt-users-with-updates